# Is there a way to optimize vector-matrix multiplication other than using loop unrolling?

Tags: algorithm, performance, optimization, matrix

There are a number of ways to improve the performance of a matrix-matrix multiplication (e.g. using the transpose of the second matrix to exploit locality of reference, using algorithmic approaches like [Strassen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Strassen_algorithm) etc.)

But is there a way to improve the performance of vector-matrix multiplication? (Even a google search for this would redirect to matrix-matrix multiplication improvement methods.) I know that we can use [loop unrolling](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Loop_unrolling) to get some amount of performance improvement, but  are there any other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the past I've used 1-dimensional matrices which are much faster to access than 2-dimensional matrices. They are also not that much harder to use, you can access each element using something like:

```
int i, j;
for (i = 0; i < COLUMN_LENGTH; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < ROW_LENGTH; j++)
    {
        printf("%f\n", A[i * ROW_LENGTH + j]);
    }
}
```

This is for a row-major ordered matrix.

The math library [LAPACK](http://www.netlib.org/lapack/) is something that you could use instead in your application, the matrix functions have been highly tuned for various architectures. Otherwise you could read the source code which might give you some ideas for your own optimizations.

Comment: Without using a library, I was trying to do the improvement myself. I'll try the 1-D array thing and see how it would perform.

Answer (score 2):

By definition, matrix-vector multiplication is a sequence of unrelated dot products. Since they are unrelated, they can be performed in parallel.

[GPU matrix-vector product (gemv)](http://www.bealto.com/gpu-gemv.html) gives a very nice & detailed comparison of different GPU parallelizations for `gem?` operations.

As with anything GPU related, the problem would need to be substantial enough to warrant the setup overhead of a GPU call to begin with. Presumably, if the column dimension of the matrix would be long enough, even CPU thread parallelization could speed things up.

---

A different direction relates to what you wrote about loop unrolling. Loop unrolling simply exploits some knowledge of computer architecture, namely that a cache miss can safely perform here out-of-order execution

```
// Code fragment for calculating the ith product entry.
for(size_t j = 0; j < n, j += 4)
{
    sum0 += m[i][j] * v[j];
    sum1 += m[i + 1][j] * v[j];
    sum2 += m[i + 2][j] * v[j];
    sum3 += m[i + 3][j] * v[j];
}
```

BLAS libraries, e.g., [OpenBLAS](http://www.openblas.net/) perform many more such micro optimizations, some of which rely on very architecture-specific features.

Comment: I was looking for something that doesn't use parallelism (hence didn't try GPUs). Thanks anyway!

Comment: No problem. Good luck.

Answer (score 0):

I think that the universal solution doesn't exist. But we can accelerate calculations with attention to specific features of calculating means of throuh using fast memory for vector, the cache memory properties and other.